# How to prevent Duplicate Object creation in ADAM?

Tags: active-directory, ldap, adam, adfs

I am testing out using ADAM and the DSML services. I have two ADAM servers, one is a replica of the other and they are Load Balanced. How can you protect duplicate object creation in the ADAM directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before you create anything, query for the name you intend to use as the naming attribute first to see if it is in use already.

I am not sure for ADAM, but for Active Directory, while the full DN of course must be unique, the sAMAccountName must also be unique within the domain.

Or else try, catch the error and return it.